# jquery datatable Pagination- fetching using Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using dataTables plugin for a table on a page I am working on. Its basically fetching rows through an ajax call and in this ajax call, I send the search params that the user selects and the page number required.
I need the Next, Previous, First and Last buttons to also fire the same ajax call, but with different page numbers, as the back-end interceptor depends on the page number.

This api call would return total no. of rows(say 1000) belonging for these search params and the rows with the page size( say 50).

Is there any way, I can use data table to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could write a click event handler for the class "paginate_button" where in you could have an ajax call something below.

```
$(".paginate_button").click(function() {
    // Ajax call.
});
```

Hope this helps!!